# How does one synchronise on premise MongoDB with an Azure DocumentDB?

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm looking for the best way that i can synchronise a on premise MongoDB with an Azure DocumentDB . the idea is this can synchronise on a predetermined time, for example every 2 hours.

I'm using .NET and C#.

I was thinking that I can create a Windows Service that retrieves the documents from de Azure DocumentDB collections and inserts the documents on my on premise MongoDB.

But I'm wondering if there is any better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my understanding, you could use [Azure Cosmos DB Data Migration Tool](https://github.com/azure/azure-documentdb-datamigrationtool) to [Export docs from collections to JSON file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data#export-to-json-file), then pick up the exported file(s) and insert / update into your on-premise MongoDB. Moreover, here is a tutorial about using the Windows Task Scheduler to backup DocumentDB, you could follow [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/backing-up-documentdb-databases/).

When executing the export operation, you could export to a local file or Azure Blob Storage. For exporting to the local file, you could leverage the `FileTrigger` from [﻿Azure WebJobs SDK Extensions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions) to monitor the file additions / changes under a particular directory, then pick up the new inserted local file and insert into your MongoDB. For exporting to Blob storage, you could also work with WebJobs SDK and use the `BlobTrigger` to trigger the new blob file and do the insertion. For the blob approach, you could follow [How to use Azure blob storage with the WebJobs SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Blobs).